# Docker without SELinux makes ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED errors in Chromium

Tags: docker, selinux

I had errors from SELinux when using files inside docker, so I've edited the file `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to disable SELinux for docker, after restart I was keep gettings errors ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED errors in Chromium.

When I stop docker service:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

The errors where gone. How can I setup docker without SELinux in a way that my network will still work?

This was also happening after I've restarted the machine. I think It was fine before restart, just after I've restarted docker, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**:

Docker was also giving some errors about network so I've stopped firewall, I'm not sure how to configure it to make it work with docker (every hint I've found suggested to turn off firewalld).

**EDIT2**

I've restored SELinux in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and restarted docker service but the CHAGE error still happen, only after stoping docker I can use browser without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to monitor the configuration of your network interfaces. Docker does initialize some network interfaces - it seems that this go wrong somehow, docker retries this -> and the network changes error occurs. Or that network manager picks up one of the new network interfaces and try to get an IP from it - then you need to instruct your network manager to ignore the interface or do a manual configuration.

Comment: How can I monitor the network interfaces, I was looking at `iftop` but it show only one IP address.

Comment: I meant something like `ifconfig`.

Comment: ifconfig gives `docker0` interface and lot of weird ones like `br-190117cf7f6e` I think they are from `docker network` (I've was watning a course about docker and they said that docker is using bridges internally) but I also have 3 weird `veth<HASH>` interfaces, I'm not sure if they came from docker.

Comment: I assume - you could stop docker, or also do a `brctl show`,

Comment: Now I only have `br-<HASH>` and `docker0`, It seems that I've had some docker containers running (it was broken app that I've tried to setup before I know anything about docker) the `veth<HASH>` interfaces was from it, stopping those containers and restarting docker solved the issue I hope. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to know you fixed it :-)